NetworkManager always failing - Eth0 not able to get IP adresse
all of a sudden, my ubuntu 24 M started not being able to get IP address and in boot, I always see

Failed to start NetworkManager-wait-online.service


here is a snapshot
On the network Icon, it keeps saying "Requesting IP......" and it turns around
I issued
nmcli devise status, I get (always )

It is on a Hyper-V host which has 2 NICS, I tried both, same problem. I tried Manual in IPv4 settings insteatd of Automatic, same thing
What might be the issue? Thanks for your help
